# jsonpickle subclass of OrderedDict not working

Tags: python-3.4, pickle, jsonpickle

What I am doing wrong:

```
class A(collections.OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self,*largs,**kwargs):
        super(A,self).__init__(*largs,**kwargs);
    def __reduce__(self):
        return super(A,self).__reduce__()

dt = collections.OrderedDict([(1,3),(34,2)]) # pickles fine
d=A([(1,3),(34,2)])                          # pickles fine

js=pickle.dumps([d,dt])
print(js)
temp = pickle.loads(js)
print(temp)

# but it does not jsonpickle.decode ????
js=jsonpickle.encode(d)
print(js)
temp = jsonpickle.decode(js)
print(temp)
```

Comment: ``print(jsonpickle.util.has_reduce(d))`` returns ``(False,False)``  why?? it has a reduce?

Answer (score 0):

Obvisouly there is a special Handler which I should have registered for my class:

`jsonpickle.handlers.register(A, handlers.OrderedDictReduceHandler)`

then it works

Comment: handlers.OrderedDictReduceHandler is depecrated now